# Looking for a course (online?) RE: systems with XY stages

Tags: control, kinematics, dynamics

Using XY stages is common in many fields:

- 3D printing
- Genetics instruments
- semiconductor lithography
- automated microscope slide imaging

See for example https://www.asml.com/en/technology/lithography-principles/mechanics-and-mechatronics

Optimizing an XY stage for:

- precision
- accuracy
- speed

Is a challenging problem of controls, structural engineering, and motion.

**Is there an online or in person course that teaches the fundamentals of systems built for these purposes?**

Perhaps a graduate level course?  Coursera? LinkedIn? Kahn Academy? a stage vendor?

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* user3533030, but I'm afraid that *Life Questions* are off-topic. Choosing how to spend your time (books to read, **classes to take,** projects to construct, career to pursue etc.) may be difficult, but it's specific to you, so unlikely to help future visitors. Questions like this are welcome in [chat] when you have the [privilege](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, see [ask] & [about].

Comment: You seem to outline three broad categories of knowledge here - controls, structural engineering, and "motion." These classes, at their most basic/introductory, are typically third-year mechanical engineering courses. Algebra leads to linear algebra and calculus, which leads to physics and static analysis, which leads to dynamic analysis, which leads to structural analysis and deformable bodies. The dynamic analysis also forks into a class of problems that are called "system dynamics" where I'm from, which goes over the dynamics of coupled bodies ("motion") and *that* class leads to controls.

Comment: I'm not sure how much you would get out of a controls course if you don't have a firm grasp on how to model a system. I don't know how well you could model a system if you can't model the dynamics of an individual. I don't know how well you could model an individual if you don't have a command of physics and differential equations. Engineering is a career path that typically takes years of classes, and again, that's to get into the "introductory" courses on the subjects.

Comment: Sorry... I'm trying to get a lot deeper than the PID loop answer.  Even deeper than the "search for resonances" answer.  I'm trying to get to the level where FEA for the structure, motion control, methods of translation, flexure mounting are all integrated into the concept.  This is why I listed the systems above.  I already have a PhD in Applied Physics, so I know a fair amount about engineering, PDEs, ODEs, linear systems, controls, material science and structural dynamics / modal analysis.

Comment: @user3533030 - If that's what you're going for, then I don't think you're going to find a satisfying class. A solution of the caliber you're describing is an engineering problem that's going to require a lot of detailed models of the components involved. I would imagine you'd start with the nominal payload, define your precision targets, allowable motion and vibration characteristics, and disturbance/tooling inputs (a milling machine and a stereolithography machine would excite the payload very differently) and then work back from there to design the payload, actuator, etc.

Comment: A term that might help is "iterative design" because once you can't pick your actuators until you've designed the fixture/platform, but then you might need to redesign the platform to allow the actuators to attach, which could affect bearings or guides included in the original design, which could cause you to go back and make a different selection for actuators, etc.